# How can I test whether a variable holds a lambda?

Tags: python, class, types, lambda

Is there a way to test whether a variable holds a `lambda`?
The context is I'd like to check a type in a unit test:

```
self.assertEquals(lambda, type(myVar))
```

The `type` seems to be "function" but I didn't see any obvious builtin type to match it.
Obviously, I could write this, but it feels clumsy:

```
self.assertEquals(type(lambda m: m), type(myVar))
```

Comment: Don't set questions as "community wiki".

Comment: I don't post answers to "wiki" questions as a rule (too many headaches), but the short answer is: don't.  Lambda isn't a type in Python, it's just shorthand to declare a function.  It's meaningless to try to distinguish between them; there is no difference.

Comment: Wouldn't say it's totally meaningless.  I'm using this answer in the context of writing experiment logs.  For reproduceability, I want to ensure that an experimental parameter  being used (including a function) is reachable by it's commit hash, `__module__`, and `__qualname__`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
def isalambda(v):
  LAMBDA = lambda:0
  return isinstance(v, type(LAMBDA)) and v.__name__ == LAMBDA.__name__
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll go for that. Just testing the type as I did is not ideal since any function will match so checking ___name___ or func_name is a good combo on top of that. Dunno how likely it is that the internal lambda name changes later though. It's still quite clumsy :-)

Comment: @ralfoids, agreed on clumsiness, but then Python `lambda`s _are_ totally clumsy all the way;-)  BTW, what difference does it make to you whether a var is a `def`'d function or `lambda`, anyway?

Comment: @ralfoide, You could use `v.__name__== (lambda: None).__name__` if you are worried about the name of `lambda` changing

Comment: @Alex and @glenn above: funny I end up writing my testing checking whether it's a function, and indeed decided not to care whether it's a lambda or a function. Still it was interesting to see it's possible to test for and I like @gnibbler's idea to not depend on a constant.

Comment: @gnibbler: A Python implementation could, in principle, give lambdas unique names, eg. based on co_filename/co_firstlineno, or use a placeholder name that's also a valid function name (eg. simply "lambda").  Maybe not ideal, but valid--better off avoiding tricks.

Comment: @alex, maybe exactly same difference as in Lisp, even the implementation is not clean: None ( or NIL :) (COMMENT 'FOR 'LISPERS)

Answer (score 50):

This is years past-due, but `callable(mylambda)` will return `True` for any callable function or method, lambdas included. `hasattr(mylambda, '__call__')` does the same thing but is much less elegant.

If you need to know if something is *absolutely exclusively* a lambda, then  I'd use:

```
callable(mylambda) and mylambda.__name__ == "<lambda>"
```

(This answer is relevant to Python2.7.5, onwards.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd suggest changing the `hasattr(mylambda, '__call__')` reference with `callable(mylambda)` -- it does the same thing under the hood, but it's a built-in feature for Python 2, documented at https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable.

Comment: I didn't even know about that-- I'm not surprised there is such a thing, but I am a bit confused that I didn't find it when I was looking this up months ago... Cool.

Comment: This is the best answer imho

Answer (score 13):

Use the `types` [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html):

```
from types import *

assert isinstance(lambda m: m, LambdaType)
```

According to the docs, It is safe to use `from types import *`.

> ATTENTION to the reader: this is wrong! `types.LambdaType is types.FunctionType`, so the above exrpession will match both Lambdas and Functions, alike.

Comment: In contrast to the accepted answer, that also works if `__name__` of the lambda function is changed.

Comment: This is wrong: types.LambdaType *is* types.FunctionType. 
That means that this will match Lambdas and Functions alike

Comment: Since there's no practical difference, this is probably the best answer.

Comment: Also works with `from types import LambdaType` instead of `from types import *` in Python 2.7

Comment: DONT USE THIS ONE IT TRICKS YOU!  See polvoazul's comment 3 up.

Comment: From https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/types.py: `LambdaType = type(lambda: None)         # Same as FunctionType`

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to do any hacks, the built in [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction) module handles it for you.

```
import inspect
print inspect.isfunction(lambda x:x)
```

Comment: There is `callable` for what you suggested, and besides, it is not what OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylambda.func_name == '<lambda>'
```

Comment: Yes, this isn't something specified by the language and it might break at any time.  Don't do it.