# How do I write a null (no-op) contextmanager in Python?

Tags: python, contextmanager

Sometimes I need a dummy context manager that does nothing. It can then be used as a stand-in for a more useful, but optional, context manager. For example:

```
ctx_mgr = <meaningfulContextManager> if <condition> else <nullContextManager>
with ctx_mgr:
    ...
```

How do I define such a trivial, empty context manager? Does the Python library offer one off the shelf?

How about cases where we want the context to be used with an `as` clause?

```
with ctx_mgr as resource:
    <operations on resource>
```

Comment: How about `if 1:` as replacement for a `with whatever:`?

Comment: This is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803059/conditional-with-statement-in-python).

Answer (score 136, accepted):

**Python 3.7 and above**: use [`contextlib.nullcontext`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext), specifically designed for this reason.

Before Python 3.7, the standard library does not offer a context manager specifically designed for these use cases, but there are some workarounds.

**Since Python 3.4**, [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) can be used for that purpose in the first case, i.e. when there is no `as` clause:

```
ctx_mgr = <meaningfulContextManager> if <condition> else contextlib.suppress()

with ctx_mgr:
    ...
```

**Since Python 3.3**, a similar work-around is also available, [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack), albeit slower than `suppress` (it takes twice as long in my tests).

**Before Python 3.3**, or **in case you need an `as` clause** before Python 3.7, developers need to roll their own.
Here is one possible implementation (see note at the bottom, but all errors are mine):

```
class NullContextManager(object):
    def __init__(self, dummy_resource=None):
        self.dummy_resource = dummy_resource
    def __enter__(self):
        return self.dummy_resource
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        pass
```

One can then write:

```
ctx_mgr = <meaningfulContextManager> if <condition> else NullContextManager(dummy_resource)

with ctx_mgr as resource:
    <operations on resource>
```

Of course, `dummy_resource` will need to support all operations required of the "meaningful" resource. So for example, if the meaningful context manager, on `__enter__()`, returns something that is made to `quack()` inside the managed block, `dummy_resource` will also need to support that, albeit possibly without doing anything at all.

```
class DummyDuck(object):
    def quack()
        # Ssssh...
        pass

ctx_mgr = <meaningfulContextManager> if <condition> else NullContextManager(DummyDuck())

with ctx_mgr as someDuck:
    someDuck.quack()
```

Source: [A Python feature request](https://bugs.python.org/issue10049). Many thanks to all those who contributed to that discussion. This is my attempt at summarising its outcome in a self-answered question, to save people time reading that long thread. Also see Python documentation's mention of [this use of `ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#simplifying-support-for-single-optional-context-managers).

Comment: The documentation mentions the ExitStack as a do-nothing context manager here https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#simplifying-support-for-single-optional-context-managers

Comment: **UPD 23 Nov, 2017**, finally, there is a commit with `nullcontext` https://bugs.python.org/issue10049#msg306770

Comment: Many thanks @maxkoryukov, I have updated the answer.

Comment: A somewhat faster do-nothing context manager available in 3.4 and up (before `nullcontext` is available) is `contextlib.suppress`. It takes varargs, and you can simply pass no exceptions to it at all: `with suppress():` will suppress nothing, and it's got a lot less overhead than `ExitStack`.

Comment: If I want to support before Python 3.3, and if I don't want to pass an argument to `NullContextManager()`, is this solution ok: `class NullContextManager:` `def __enter__(self): pass` `def __exit__(self, *args): pass`?

Answer (score 14):

A simple solution for Python 3.6 and below, including 2.7:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def nullcontext(enter_result=None):
    yield enter_result
```

Since Python 3.7 you should use the provided [`contextlib.nullcontext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. Should your code be located in the calling file, right?

Answer (score 6):

Since Python 3.2, `memoryview(b'')` can be use as a no-op context manager. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview.release.

**Pros**

- No imports required
- Works on 3.2+
- Roughly twice as fast as `contextlib.nullcontext`

**Cons**

- You probably want to add a `# no-op` comment.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for Python 2.7, not yet mentioned in the answers:

```py
from contextlib import nested
with nested():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.7+ , you can use

```
import contextlib
with (lambda noop_func: contextlib.contextmanager(noop_func))(lambda: (yield))():
    print("hi")
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  This works, and answers the question accurately.  It's an in-line no-op context manager

Comment: [I didn't downvote] hey found your answer, thought you might like to see mine from before I found this stackoverflow post: `namedtuple("FreeScope",("scope",))(lambda:type("FreeContext",tuple(),{"__enter__":lambda_,__=None,___=None,____=None:None,"__exit__":lambda_,__=None,___=None,____=None:None,},))`

Answer (score -5):

I just used `threading.Lock()` as a dummy context manager. Temporary lock, only used by the context manager.