# Conditional with statement with multiple variables in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, with-statement

I would like to accept a certain number (limited to - say, 3) to evaluate a condition within the a `with` statement. I did find it's possible to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803059/conditional-with-statement-in-python). Can I do something similar to the following in the `with` statement by evaluating a condition:

```
def foo(num):
    with open("1.txt","a") as f1, open("2.txt") as f2 <<if num >= 2>>, open("3.txt") as f3 <<if num >= 3>>:
        if num >= 1:
            f1.write("1")
            if num >= 2:
                f2.write("2")
                if num >= 3:
                    f3.write("3")
```

Is this possible? Is there any other way I can evaluate an if condition for the objects involved in a `with` statement so that I use exactly the same number of objects as in `num`?

**P.S.** : This code above is just an example using files, it can be replaced by objects too.

Comment: @reportgunner It is not. I'm aware of that. More interested in the condition I've marked within << >>.

Comment: Why do you absolutely want a `with` statement? I feel like it would be easier to just manually open and close the files here

Comment: @Nakor With allows me not to close the files explicitly.

Comment: How does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4617069/476) *not* help?! You make a *list of files* and iterate over them.

Comment: @deceze I have updated the post to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @skrowten_hermit your example is very arbitrary. We don't know what is the relationship between `f1` `f2` and `f3` and we don't know what is the reason you insist on using with statement like this. Why don't you do the logic first, store the result in a variable and then work with files as required ? (even _one by one_ ?)

Comment: @skrowten_hermit I think your questions lies on the syntax definition of the `with` statement. Your construction is not syntactically correct. More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)

Comment: `files = ['%d.txt' % i for i in range(1, num + 1)]` – That's your list of files. Then you do the [`ExitStack` way of opening them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4617069/476). Then you do `for i, file in enumerate(files, 1): file.write(i)`. That's the way to do this with a dynamic number of files. No nested or inline `if` statements needed.

Comment: @Layo Okay. I did go through that. I just wanted to know if I could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803059/conditional-with-statement-in-python). So that I can declare only those many objects as required or defined by the variable `num`.