# Combining if and with in python?

Tags: python

I was wondering if it was possible to use the with statement conditionally, like

```
if condition:
    with mock.patch(....)
#code that is or is not patched
```

Is it theoretically possible to achieve this without losing the with statement?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here.  Please create a more comprehensive example that shows the desired behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by losing the `with` statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional with statement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803059/conditional-with-statement-in-python)

Comment: I assume that you want with to apply to the code below the comment if condition is met. There may be a better way to do so - please share a longer piece of code so we'd see the context.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper context manager that calls the wrapped context manager's `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods based on the given condition:

```
class conditional_context_manager:
    def __init__(self, condition, context_manager):
        self.condition = condition
        self.context_manager = context_manager

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.context_manager.__enter__() if self.condition else self

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.condition:
            return self.context_manager.__exit__(*args, **kwargs)
```

so that:

```
with conditional_context_manager(False, mock.patch('builtins.print')):
    print('hi')
```

outputs:

```
hi
```

while:

```
with conditional_context_manager(True, mock.patch('builtins.print')):
    print('hi')
```

outputs nothing.

Alternatively, you can use a `mock.MaigicMock` object as a context manager if the condition is not met:

```
with mock.patch('builtins.print') if condition else mock.MagicMock():
    #code that is or is not patched
```