# One context manager instead of two for open file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

My question looks similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803059/conditional-with-statement-in-python) but not sure... I want to parse some log files that are sometimes compressed in gzip sometimes not.

I've got the following:

```
if file[-3:] == ".gz":
     with gzip.open(file, 'rb') as f:
          # do something
else:
    with open(file) as f:
          # do the same thing.
```

Is it possible to have only one `with` statement ?

Comment: it may be possible, but I think it would be more confusing. perhaps just put the `something` in a function so you don't duplicate your code.

Comment: Did you try `with ... if ... else ...´?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the conditional statement in the `with` line:

```
with gzip.open(file, 'rb') if file[-3:] == '.gz' else open(file) as f:
   processFile(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fn = gzip.open if file.endswith('.gz') else open

with fn(file, 'rb') as f:
    ...
```

Also note that the call to the function returning the context manager does not have to happen inside the `with` line:

```
if file.endswith('.gz'):
    ctx = gzip.open(file, 'rb')
else:
    ctx = open(file)

with ctx as f:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your "Do Something" in a function

```
def processFile(f)
        Do Something...

if file[-3:] == ".gz":
     with gzip.open(file, 'rb') as f:
          processFile(f)
else:
    with open(file) as f:
          processFile(f)
```