# How to support optional stdin/stdout using context managers?

Tags: python, stdout, stdin, contextmanager

Suppose I want to implement a Python script with the following signature:

```
myscript.py INPUT OUTPUT
```

...where `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` stand for the ***paths of files*** the script will read from and write to, respectively.

The code for implementing a script with such a signature may feature the following construct:

```
with open(inputarg, 'r') as instream, open(outputarg, 'w') as outstream:
    ...
```

...where here the `inputarg` and `outputarg` variables hold the file paths (which are strings) passed to the script via its `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` command-line arguments.

---

Nothing special or unusual so far.

But now, suppose that, for version 2 of the script, I want to give the user the option to pass the special value `-` for either (or both) of its arguments, to indicate that the script should, respectively, read from `stdin` and write to `stdout`.

In other words, I want that all the forms below produce the same results:

```
myscript.py INPUT OUTPUT
myscript.py   -   OUTPUT  <INPUT
myscript.py INPUT   -             >OUTPUT
myscript.py   -     -     <INPUT  >OUTPUT
```

Now, the `with` statement given earlier is no longer suitable.  For one thing, either expression `open('-', 'r')` or `open('-', 'w')` would raise an exception:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-'
```

---

I have not been able to come up with a *convenient* way to extend the `with`-based construct above to accommodate the desired new functionality.

For example, this variation won't work (on top of being somewhat unwieldy), because `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` do not implement the context manager interface:

```
with sys.stdin if inputarg == '-' else open(inputarg, 'r'), \
        sys.stdout if outputarg == '-' else open(outputarg, 'w'):
    ...
```

---

The only thing I can come up (maybe) is to define a minimal pass-through wrapper class that implements the context manager interface, like this:

```
class stream_wrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.__dict__['_stream'] = stream

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._stream, attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        return setattr(self._stream, attr, value)

    def close(self, _std=set(sys.stdin, sys.stdout)):
        if not self._stream in _std:
            self._stream.close()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self._stream

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        return self.close()
```

...and then write the `with` statement like this:

```
with stream_wrapper(sys.stdin if inputarg == '-' else open(inputarg, 'r')), \
        stream_wrapper(sys.stdout if outputarg == '-' else open(outputarg, 'w')):
    ...
```

The `stream_wrapper` class strikes me as a lot of drama for what it achieves (assuming that it works at all: I have not tested it!).

Is there a simpler way to get the same results?

**IMPORTANT:** Any solution to this problem must take care never to close `sys.stdin` or `sys.stdout`.

Comment: Some of the ideas at https://stackoverflow.com/q/27803059/ might be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a [contextlib.contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) this can be managed with something like:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys

@contextmanager
def stream(arg, mode='r'):
    if mode not in ('r', 'w'):
        raise ValueError('mode not "r" or "w"')
    if arg == '-':
        yield sys.stdin if mode == 'r' else sys.stdout
    else:
        with open(arg, mode) as f:
            yield f

with (stream(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fin,
      stream(sys.argv[2], 'w') as fout
):
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line)
```

If not familiar with `contextmanager` it basically runs the code up to the `yield` on entry and after the `yield` on exit.  Wrapping the `yield` of the `open` in a `with` ensures it is closed if used.

Answer (score 1):

[`argparse.FileType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects) understands this convention:

> FileType objects understand the pseudo-argument '-' and automatically convert this into `sys.stdin` for readable `FileType` objects and `sys.stdout` for writable `FileType` objects.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, FileType


p = ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("input", type=FileType())
p.add_argument("output", type=FileType('w'))
args = p.parse_args()
```

`args.input` and `args.output` will be file-like objects opened and ready for reading/writing. (And since `FileType` may simply return `sys.stdin` or `sys.stdout`, neither should be used with a `with` statement.)