# if else condition for with statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, with-statement

I have a condition that can be either `True` or `False` and depending on this condition I want to run a block of code inside a `with` statement or not, something like this:

```
if use_with:
    with bla_bla_bla:
        # Block of code
else:
    # Block of code
```

This does work, but it is a horrible code duplication prompt to problems in the future. What is the way of doing this?

Comment: Use functions. Write function code once, use multiple times.

Comment: Still have to duplicate the call to the function.

Comment: Do you control `bla_bla_bla` or is it a third-party or built-in context manager?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803059/conditional-with-statement-in-python

Comment: But how can the same block of code be executed within the context created by a `with` or outside of it?